# Retrying on Connection Reset

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm using `urllib.request` to download files from the internet. However sometimes I get `Connection Reset by Peer` and I want to retry.

I tried the following, but it seems that e.errno contains `socket error` and not an actual errno:

```
while True:
  try:
    filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
    break
  except IOError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
      raise
  except Exception as e:
    raise
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this part is not needed, first of all.

```
except Exception as e:
    raise
```

And the arguments of the IOError is the type of error (socket error) and the error given to it. This error, in turn, is not the original error, but that error is in the args, so...

```
except IOError as e:
    if e.args[1].args[0].errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
       raise
```

Should work. I don't have a server that will reset on me, so I can't test it 100% But it works with ECONNREFUSED. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Good catch on Exception.