# Recovering from ECONNRESET in Python/Mechanize

Tags: python, error-handling, tcp, mechanize

I've got a large bulk downloading application written in Python/Mechanize, aiming to download something like 20,000 files.  Clearly, any downloader that big is occasionally going to run into some `ECONNRESET` errors.  Now, I know how to handle [each of these individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605929/retrying-on-connection-reset), but there's two problems with that:

1. I'd really rather not wrap every single outbound web call in a try/catch block.
2. Even if I were to do so, there's trouble with knowing how to handle the errors once the exception has thrown.  If the code is just

   ```
   data = browser.response().read()
   ```

   then I know precisely how to deal with it, namely:

   ```
   data = None
   while (data == None):
       try:
           data = browser.response().read()
       except IOError as e:
           if e.args[1].args[0].errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
               raise
           data = None
   ```

   but if it's just a random instance of

   ```
   browser.follow_link(link)
   ```

   then how do I know what Mechanize's internal state looks like if an `ECONNRESET` is thrown somewhere in here?  For example, do I need to call `browser.back()` before I try the code again?  What's the proper way to recover from that kind of error?

EDIT: The solution in the accepted answer certainly works, and in my case it turned out to be not so hard to implement.  I'm still academically interested, however, in whether there's an error handling mechanism that could result in quicker error catching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps place the try..except block higher up in the chain of command:

```
import collections
def download_file(url):
    # Bundle together the bunch of browser calls necessary to download one file.
    browser.follow_link(...)
    ...
    response=browser.response()
    data=response.read()

urls=collections.deque(urls)

while urls:
    url=urls.popleft()
    try:
        download_file(url)
    except IOError as err:
        if err.args[1].args[0].errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
            raise
        else:
            # if ECONNRESET error, add the url back to urls to try again later
            urls.append(url)
```

Comment: I was thinking of this as the "nuclear option" if there's no better way for an error handler.  Thanks!

Comment: @Charles Pence: you could make it smarter, but that would involve placing try..except blocks around each web call and handling each error on a case-by-case basis ... I doubt there is anything better one can do than that, since only the programmer can decide what the appropriate action should be in case of failure at any given point.

Comment: Actually, this proved easier to implement than I'd thought.  Thanks guys!

Comment: @Charles Pence: you could cache/memoize the results of intermediate steps, so that when you call `download_file(url)` a second time, successful web calls can be skipped.